# How to authenticate a user in X11 without gksudo/gksu/pkexec

Tags: x11, sudo, pkexec

Are there any alternatives to using gksudo/gksu or pkexec to authenticate users in X11?  The only one that comes to mind is creating a wrapper script that uses sudo to ensure my 2-factor authentication is handled, but then I'm stuck with a terminal window running while the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple wrapper:

cat /usr/bin/sudo-askpass

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --password
```

cat /usr/bin/keepassxc

```
#!/bin/bash
SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/sudo-askpass sudo unshare -n sudo -u $USER /usr/bin/keepassxc.original $KEEPASSX_FILE
```

I've had issues with pkexec and gksudo / gksu.